# Validate inputs in a calculator - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've written this calculator for payment cost. Now I need to check if the input isn't empty + is a number, otherwise throw an error to say that "The field can't be empty". I started adding it but got confused along in the process. What's the best/cleanest way to handle error handling in this example? Maybe I should put the error handling job into a separate component?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import styles from "./../styles.module.less";

class Calc extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            popoverOpen: false,
            cost: 0,
            homePrice: 0,
            downPaymentAmt: 0,
            downPaymentPrc: 0,
            termOfLoan: 0,
            annualInterestRate: 0,
            formError: '',
            inputValid: false
        };
    }

    handleStateChange = e => {
        const {
            target: { name, value },
        } = e;

        this.setState({ [name]: value });

    };
    handleCostChange = () => {
        const {
            homePrice,
            downPaymentAmt,
            termOfLoan,
            annualInterestRate,
        } = this.state;
        const principal = homePrice - downPaymentAmt;
        const lengthOfLoan = 12 * termOfLoan;
        const percentageRate = annualInterestRate / 1200;
        // Formula M = P[i(1+i)^n]/[(1+i)^n -1]
        const cost =
            (principal * percentageRate) /
            (1 - Math.pow(1 + percentageRate, lengthOfLoan * -1)).toString();
        this.setState({
            cost: cost.toFixed(2),
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className={styles.row}>

                    <div className={styles.col12}>
                        <h1 className={styles.calch1}>
                           Your home-buying by numbers
                        </h1>
                        <div
                            className={`${styles.positionRelative} ${
                                styles.formGroup
                            }`}>
                            <label htmlFor="name" >
                                Home price
                            </label>
                            <label s" formError={this.state.formError}>The field can't be empty</label>
                            <div className={styles.inputGroup}>
                                <div className={styles.inputGroupPrepend}>
                                    <span className={styles.inputGroupText}>
                                        $
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    id="input3-group1"
                                    className={styles.formControl}
                                    name="homePrice"
                                    value={this.state.value}
                                    onChange={this.handleStateChange}
                                    placeholder="Amount of home's selling price"
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.row}>
                    <div className={styles.col12}>
                        <div
                            className={`${styles.positionRelative} ${
                                styles.formGroup
                            }`}>
                            <label htmlFor="name" className="">
                                Loan program
                            </label>
                            <div className={styles.inputGroup}>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    id="name"
                                    required=""
                                    className={styles.formControl}
                                    name="termOfLoan"
                                    value={this.state.value}
                                    onChange={this.handleStateChange}
                                    placeholder="Original number of years to pay off your mortgage"
                                />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                    <div className={`${styles.col6} ${styles.colsm4}`}>
                        <div
                            className={`${styles.positionRelative} ${
                                styles.formGroup
                            }`}>
                            <label
                                htmlFor="name"
                                className=""
                                style={{ display: "block" }}>
                                &nbsp;
                            </label>
                            <button
                                className={`${styles.btn} ${
                                    styles.btnWarning
                                } ${styles.btnSm}`}
                                style={{
                                    fonSize: 16,
                                    height: "35px",
                                    color: "white",
                                }}
                                onClick={this.handleCostChange}>
                                Calculate!
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.row}>
                    <div className={styles.col}>
                        <h2 className={styles.calch2}>
                          Your monthly mortgage 
                        </h2>
                        <div className={styles.tableResponsive}>
                            <table
                                className={`${styles.borderLess} ${
                                    styles.table
                                }`}>
                                {/* <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Estimated monthly</th>
                                        <th>taxes</th>
                                        <th>Insurance</th>
                                        <th>P&amp;I</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead> */}
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr className={styles.output}>
                                        <td>
                                            ${this.state.cost.toLocaleString()}
                                        </td>
                                       <td className={styles.tdlabel}>
                                           PER MONTH
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Calc;
```

Comment: I think you've put too much in a single component. You can probably split each input field into its own component with validation. They do look very similar as well so maybe a single new component with customisation props will be enough

Comment: Sure but can you help me figure this out first at least in the example of one input?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for `onBlur` event. It occurs when the user leaves an input field. So, add `onBlur` event listener in your input field.

eg : For homePrice

```
<input
      type="text"
      id="input3-group1"
      className={styles.formControl}
      name="homePrice"
      // assign value as this.state.homePrice
      value={this.state.homePrice}
      // Add onBlur and use handleValidation event handler
      onBlur={this.handleValidation}
      onChange={this.handleStateChange}
      placeholder="Amount of home's selling price"
  />

// for testing add this line just below the input field 
// it will display form error              
{ this.state.formError && <span>{this.state.formError} </span> }
```

Now add `handleValidation` method to your component

```
handleValidation = (e) => {
         let { value } = e.target
         // check if value is empty or not       
         if (value.trim().length === 0) {
            this.setState({formError: 'Input field is required'}) 
            return
         // check if value is number or not
         } else if (isNaN(Number(value))) {
            this.setState({formError: 'Input field value must be a number'}) 
            return
        } else {
            this.setState({ formError: ''})
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

```
handleCostChange = (e) => {
        // for testing only not needed
        let { value } = e.target; 
        // Checking whether "e.target.value" on button is empty or not
        console.log('some',value,'text') // some text
        console.log(value.trim().length === 0)  // true

        const {
            homePrice,
            downPaymentAmt,
            termOfLoan,
            annualInterestRate,
        } = this.state;

        // updates
        if (homePrice.trim().length === 0) {
            this.setState({formError: 'Input Fields are required'}) 
            return
        } else if (isNaN(Number(homePrice))) {
            this.setState({formError: 'Input Fields must be number'}) 
            return
        }

        const principal = homePrice - downPaymentAmt;
        const lengthOfLoan = 12 * termOfLoan;
        const percentageRate = annualInterestRate / 1200;
        // Formula M = P[i(1+i)^n]/[(1+i)^n -1]
        const cost =
            (principal * percentageRate) /
            (1 - Math.pow(1 + percentageRate, lengthOfLoan * -1)).toString();
        this.setState({
            cost: cost.toFixed(2),
            // update
            formError: ''
        });
    };
```

And also change

```
this.state = {homePrice: 0}
```

to

```
this.state = {homePrice: ''}
```

This is needed because I have used `trim()` method which is a string method. So when you submit without touching the input field you will get an error.

Comment: thank you! And what if I want it to work just on the onclick event? I added thiis function onclick but it fires all the time whether the input is empty or not

Comment: yes it will always fire because we are using `event.target.value`. And when it is used  with `onClick` on button it will check the button value where `onClick` was attached not the input field so `event.target.value` will always will be an `empty` string. If you want to check when button is clicked you should use state value. If you need it I will add that to the answer.